# Android: Orientation Sensor not working on Tablet

Tags: android

Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION is working fine on mobile but its not working on tablet.

```
List<Sensor> mySensors = mySensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

if(mySensors.size() > 0)
{
  Toast.makeText(this, "Start ORIENTATION Sensor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
  Toast.makeText(this, "No ORIENTATION Sensor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` constant [is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ORIENTATION). Use [`SensorManager.getOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) instead.

Comment: Hi alexkorep, thanks for your reply. I used getOrientation but its not working on tablet. Can you suggest some example for Type_Orientation using getOrientation.

Answer (score 0):

I used SensorManager.getOrientation() its also working in phone but not in tablet.

```
float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;
float RR[] = new float[9];
float I[] = new float[9];
float orientation[] = new float[3];

SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
Sensor mMageneticField = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mMageneticField,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

// Inside onSensorChanged

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
{   
mGravity = event.values.clone();    
}
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
{
    mGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();
}

SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RR, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
SensorManager.getOrientation(RR, orientation);
azimuth = orientation[0];
pitch = orientation[1];
roll = orientation[2];
System.out.println("Pitch " + pitch);
```